# RubyMine says ruby not installed, but is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

When I open up a Rails project in RubyMine, I get the error message, "Required ruby-3.3.0 is not installed." However, I enter the command *ruby --version* and the terminal outputs ruby 3.3.0. What's wrong?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/configuring-language-interpreter.html

Answer (score 1):

In RubyMine you have to set your SDK in the settings for each project.

Click on Rubymine in the title bar

Click on the disclosure triangle for Languages and Frameworks

Click on Ruby SDK and Gems

You should see a list of installed Rubies. Select the radio button for your Ruby and hit the OK button.

Comment: It says rbenv: 3.3.0, I assume because I installed Ruby 3.0 using the rbenv tool. Would this be a problem?

Comment: Not at all. RubyMine will list all of the ruby versions you install and allow you to choose one for your project.

Comment: In that case, is there any other reason that I would get a "Required ruby-3.3.0 is not installed." error message on starting RubyMine?

Comment: Even with 3.3.0 selected in the rubymine settings? Just to be clear, did you do any of the installs (rbenv or ruby) using sudo?

Comment: I did not. I installed it with Homebrew, and I didn't install that with sudo either.

Comment: Rubymine should recognize any rubies installed by rbenv. But have you done `rbenv rehash` ? And you can run `which ruby` in your terminal and make sure that is the same path as shown in the Rubymine sttings. In the settings where you choose the ruby interpreter there is an eyeball at the top of the list that will show the path of the installed rubies. Make sure those match with the `which... ` command. And finally open the built in terminal in Rubymine (View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal) and run the `ruby -v ` and `which ruby` commands.

Comment: Rubymine docs has this info that might help. Check out the diagnostics part: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/ruby-version-managers.html#auto_switch

Comment: Using the which command, I see Ruby installed under the path /Users/myname/.rbenv/shims/ruby. Judging by SDK configuration error I get when I try to specify that in my RubyMine settings, it appears to be an invalid path. On the other hand, it does accept /Users/myname/versions/3.3.0/bin/ruby, but says that SDK already exists when I try to select it.

Comment: My bad, when I do `which..` it shows the shims path, but when I show the paths in Rubymine it shows the full path in versions.

Comment: Could be you have something corrupt in the setting file for that project in Rubymine. From what I can see it SHOULD detect your rbenv setup automatically. In my .zshrc file I do have `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`

Comment: And can't believe I didn't ask this, but what OS are you on? If you are on Windows you have to use WSL. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html . And finally have you tried creating a new project and setting the ruby interpreter to see if it happens across all projects?